# loading a list of variables into a sqlalchemy text query

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have an existing sql-query which is executed manually:

```
define team = "'user1', 'user2', 'user3'"
select * from table
where field in (&team)
```

I want that script to be executed out of a python code. The team information shall be loaded out of a text file (so that the list can be maintained without changing the code). The sql query is also in a separate file.

Team.txt:

```
'user1', 'user2', 'user3'
```

sql-file:

```
select * from table
where field in :team
```

Python extract:

```
team = path.Path('team.txt').read_text()
sqlfile = path.Path('sql_script.sql').read_text()
str_sql = sqla.text(sqlfile)
results = conn.execute(str_sql, {"team":team}).fetchall()
print (results)
```

But unfortunately, the code returns
[(0,)]

When I change the teams-file to only one user entry, e.g. user3, then a result <>0 is returned. So the rest of the code works...

Working with a tuple does not work (NotSupportedError: (cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError) Python value of type tuple not supported.)

I am sure that I am doing something wrong with the data formats, but I have no clue how to solve that problem. Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot!